# Visualise/compare numpy arrays from Matlab/Octave to matplotlib

Tags: matlab, numpy, matplotlib, signal-processing, octave

I'm new to python and matplotlib, and I'd like to visualise / compare 3 mfcc files stored as numpy arrays in txt format.
I have the Octave code below, and I'd like to know how it can be done using python/matplotlib.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
load /dir/k11.txt  
load /dir/t11.txt  
load /dir/a11.txt  

subplot(1,2,1);imagesc(j11);axis('xy');colormap(jet);colorbar;subplot(1,2,2);imagesc(t11);axis('xy');colormap(jet);colorbar;  

c=[k11(:,end),k11(:,1:end-1)];  
figure(1);  
Ncep=size(c,2)-1;  
a=real(fft([c,zeros(size(c,1),512-Ncep*2-1),c(:,end:-1:2)]'));  
imagesc(a(1:end/2,:));  
axis('xy');  
colormap(jet);  

c=t11;  
figure(2);  
Ncep=size(c,2)-1;  
a=real(fft([c,zeros(size(c,1),512-Ncep*2-1),c(:,end:-1:2)]'));  
imagesc(a(1:end/2,:));  
axis('xy');  
colormap(jet);  

c=a11;  
figure(3);  
Ncep=size(c,2)-1;  
a=real(fft([c,zeros(size(c,1),512-Ncep*2-1),c(:,end:-1:2)]'));  
imagesc(a(1:end/2,:));  
axis('xy');  
colormap(jet);
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously your example has externalities so I can't reproduce it directly, but in
general here is an octave example and its equivalent python one using the image features you require.

#### in Octave

```matlab
% Read an image from a url 
Url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/utkuozbulak/singular-value-decomposition-on-images/master/data/grayscale_cat.jpg';
A   = imread( Url );

imagesc( A );      % Show image in 'colour-scaled' form
axis xy            % Reverse the origin of the y-axis
colormap( jet );   % Choose the jet colormap
```

#### in Python3

```python
import urllib.request             # needed for reading urls
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   # needed for imread/imshow
import matplotlib.colors as cl    # needed for colour-scaling

# Read an image from a url
Url = urllib.request.urlopen( 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/utkuozbulak/singular-value-decomposition-on-images/master/data/grayscale_cat.jpg' )
A   = plt.imread( Url, 'jpg' )

plt.imshow( A,               # Create a pyplot 'image' instance
    norm = cl.Normalize(),   # Choose colour-scaled form
    origin = 'lower',        # Reverse the origin of the y-axis
    cmap = 'jet'             # Choose the jet colormap
)

plt.show()
```

Comment: That's a point I can start from. Thank you

Comment: @lima0 My pleasure. Also welcome to Stackoverflow. You can upvote good answers, and you can also 'accept' one (if you feel it is the most 'correct' answer) by clicking on the tick mark. If you think this answer does any of the above please upvote/accept accordingly :)